# how to make div size fixed?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a problem in my project, where the size of the div varies, which shouldn't happen. I#ve put an example which shows it.

```css
html, body, .grid-container { height: 100%; margin: 0; }

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1px 1px;
}

._ {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 120px 120px;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1px 1px;
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 4 / 4;
}

.A { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 2;
    align-self: flex-end;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
    }

.B { grid-area: 1 / 2 / 3 / 3;
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
    }


.grid-container *:after { 
 content:attr(class);
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}

.circle {
  width: 115px;
  height: 115px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="_">
    <div class="A">
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="B"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you do not pu the circle div in, A & B are the same height. But as soon as you put it into the A div, the size changes to perfectly equal the one of the circle, which I totally do not want to happen.
Since I'm building a Connect 4 game and I use the Border for the "GameField" it has to stay the same size.

I've already tried adding the parameter `height: 690;` to the A div (every circle is 115px->6 circles = 690)  but then the align end did not work anymore. I also change between `align-self: end;` and `align-self: flex-end;` but that didn't change anything...

If what Im searching for isn't possible, I would love to know how else I can achieve a outline of a specificities set of cells in a css grid.

Thank you so much in advance for helping (or at least trying) me. <3

Answer (score 2):

I didn't understand literally, but you can try and use this instead of above.

I think you can add the features you want (such as height) to this code I wrote.

```css
.grid-container {
    display: inline-table;
}
._ {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 120px 120px;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 1px 1px;
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 4 / 4;
}
.grid-container *:not(.circle):after {
    content: attr(class);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
._ > div {
    border: 1px solid red;
    align-self: end;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
}
.circle {
    width: 115px;
    height: 115px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 100px;
    align-self: end;
}
.B {
    height: 20px;
}
.C {
    height: 30px;
}
.D {
    height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="_">
    <div class="A">
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="B"></div>
  <div class="C"></div><div class="D"></div></div>
</div>
```

You don't have to use css for .A and .B, you're able to use like code above. Also I added two div to better understand

If I misunderstood, send me message back, I'll check again

Comment: My problem is, that even in your example if I put align-self: end; to always have the circle at the bottom of the div, the div adjusts its size too the circle instead of remaining the original size

Comment: It would be a workaround if there was a way to make the css grid visible but only some parts of course

Comment: I edited according to what you say @JGStyle please check again. I hope it would be right now

Comment: Also you can change height and width of class .B .C and .D. Automaticlly, the circle never won't be affected